# rosbridge_suite to recieve meshes

Tags: ros, urdf, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using rosbridge_suite to visualize the robot on a windows machine in VR.
Ideally, I would like to recieve the complete robot's description directly from the robot.

I managed to recieve the plain URDF xml via "/rosapi/getparam robot_description".

Is there any possiblity to load the meshes which are referenced in the URDF in a similar way?
Or do I have to copy them manually?

Thank you for your advise!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252374/rosbridge_suite-to-recieve-meshes/) by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem by writing a ROS service that requires a "package://..." filename as input and returns the contents of that file. It is basically a very simple read-only ROS file server.

I like this solution since:

- i do not need to set up additional server beside ROSbridge
- in contrast to the ros3djs solution, i can load the meshes directly from the ROS PC and do not need any external repositories.
- i can read the Collada mesh files in a very similar way as i read the urdf JSON message on the client side.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) with karma: 71 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-20**:
Nice.

So where is it ;) ?

**Comment by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) on 2017-10-13**:
I didn't forget your question. We published the code open source recently. See https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/tree/master/file_server

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
Very nice! And very good to see that you got things to work so nicely.

Thanks for reporting back. That is much appreciated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
ROS # looks like an awesome tool. +many for making that available.

If you haven't already, consider announcing it on [ROS Discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/c/ros-projects). That should get it the attention it would seem to deserve.

**Comment by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) on 2017-10-13**:
Thank you! We brought it open source only recently. We haven't made much advertisement outside the company (yet). We are looking for supporters for that project. Feel free to support me spreading the word! :-)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
I can't post an announcement of *your* project on Discourse. That'll have to be you :).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you also using Robot Web Tools (ie: `roslibjs`, `ros3djs` etc), or just the JSON bridging functionality of `rosbridge_suite`?

I ask because in the Robot Web Tools URDF demo ([here](http://robotwebtools.org/demos/urdf.html)) loads meshes over HTTP from a web server. That seems like something you could mimic / copy.

Perhaps even write a Python node that looks at the `robot_description` parameter on the ROS PC, resolves the `package://..` URIs to their location on the disk and then services HTTP `GET` requests for those resources.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) on 2017-01-19**:
Thanks for these hints gvdhoorn!
(Multiple comments due to limited space...)

I currently use rosbridge_suite only:
On the client side, I resolve the JSON messages driectly in C#, without using any of those great javascript libraries from Robot Web Tools.

**Comment by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) on 2017-01-19**:
If I understood the Robot Web Tools URDF demo right, the meshes are downloaded from a server, and are not communicated via rosbridge:
http://wiki.ros.org/ros3djs#Mesh_Resource_Hosting

**Comment by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) on 2017-01-19**:
Setting up a http server beside the ROSbridge server on the ROS PC definitely is an option. I was already think about doing it that way. But I was hoping that ROS(bridge) had the possiblity to send the mesh data in a similar way to the URDF data.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-19**:
No, rosbridge is really just a JSON bridge into a ROS node graph. That means topics, services, actions and parameters (so urdfs), but meshes are not part of that (they're just regular files that happen to be referenced by the urdf). It would be nice though, and I'm sure there would be interest.